# MongoDB update value by reducing it by a percentage

Tags: mongodb

I have a price field, and I would like to alter the `price` field by reducing it by a flat 20 percent. I've looked at $inc and figured maybe I could use negatives to reduce the value, but not sure how.

```
db.shop.update({"name":"television"}, {"$inc": {"price": 1200 ...}});
```

What would be the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`$mul`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/#up._S_mul) but you'd need too apply the 20% reduction manually with your multiplicator value;

```
db.shop.update({"name":"television"}, {$mul: {"price": 0.8}});
```

so `0.8` meaning a 20% reduction

So you will get;

```
{
    "name": "television",
    "price": 960,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, how about an increase in a certain  percent? I couldn't figure out a way to  do it.  User.updateMany({totalSavings: {$gt:99}}, {$inc: {totalSavings: {$mul: {totalSavings: 0.002083}}}})